# Sql time(7) field not storing in DB from node js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, t-sql, sql-server-2016, node-mssql

I am using  nodemssql package for sql server azure

**Field**

> time(7)

```
>   RecurrenceType.columns.add('StartTime', mssql.Time(7));
>   RecurrenceType.columns.add('EndTime', mssql.Time(7));
```

**Values**

```
Start time : '01:01'

End time   : '13:01'
```

**stored in db as :**

```
StartTime           EndTime
00:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000
```

Please suggest how can store the value in time(7) field with nodemssql package with the exact value

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
>   protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 3 (""), row 1,
>   column 4: Data type 0x29 has an invalid data length or metadata length

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Profiler in order to see what's happening during the execution?

Comment: Yes , I checked the SQL profile , but the execution is not going into profiler . I can't see in profiler

Answer (score 0):

Furqan,

So long as your table column is configured as TIME(7) you should be able to insert directly into the column with any time string that has an accuracy of up to and including 9:

```
DECLARE @TimeString varchar(50) = '09:47:11.455651236'
DECLARE @TimeFormat AS time(7) = @TimeString
PRINT @TimeString
PRINT @TimeFormat
```

This is obviously if the string provided is in "hh:mi:ss.mmmmmmmmm". If the string is provided in any format other than this or exceeds a precision of 9 then the insert/update will fail with:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, 
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

You'll need to modify the time string accordingly if this happens to comply with the time field requirements.

Comment: I  have change time(7) to time(0) and  passing value as '01:01:00' but getting error as The data for table-valued parameter "@RecurrenceType" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is: 8037, state: 80

Comment: Furqan, Just pass the time as a varchar or string and SQL will do the conversion to TIME in the background automagically

Comment: LinkOps, I will try, but I have question, why time type is not working as parameter ?

Comment: Furqan, From what I can see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#data-types the datatype should be specified as `sql.Time(7)` and not `mssql.Time(7)`

Comment: var mssql = require("mssql"); because I have given the name as mssql instead of const sql = require('mssql')

Comment: In that case, I have no idea why it's not working. I tend to do asp.net c# and just use Time(7) directly when needed.